# Npgsql error after changing Windows Local Network Security policy

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, security, npgsql, ntlmv2

Our company has recently started doing business with a partner that is trying to give us a Web-based RDP connection into their systems.  As a part of their setup documentation, they are requiring us to change the Local Network Security policy for our workstations: specifically, changing the **LAN Manager authentication level** setting from the previous ***Send LM & NTLM responses*** to ***Send NTLMv2 response only***.  Once I make this change and **`gpupdate /force`** the changes to the workstation (which then shows the policy "correctly" set), I can RDP into our new partner's server just fine, but all of my applications that connect to the PostgreSQL database file with the following error:

```
FATAL: XX000: could not accept SSPI security context
```

I've built a little temporary application to test the connection in Visual Studio with the following code (network details redacted):

```
Imports Npgsql
Imports System.DirectoryServices

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim PGUserName As String
        Dim PGDB As NpgsqlConnection = Nothing
        Dim PGConnection As NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
        Dim PGCommand As NpgsqlCommand = Nothing
        Dim PGAdapter As NpgsqlDataAdapter = Nothing
        Dim TestSQL As String = String.Empty
        Dim TestData As New DataTable

        PGUserName = GetActiveDirectoryUsername()

        TestSQL = "SELECT * FROM testdb"
        PGConnection = New NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder

        With PGConnection
            NpgsqlEventLog.Level = LogLevel.Debug
            NpgsqlEventLog.LogName = "C:\TEST\NPGSQLEVENTLOG.TXT"
            .Host = "<PGSQLSERVER>"
            .Port = <PORT>
            .UserName = PGUserName
            .IntegratedSecurity = True
            .Database = "testing"
        End With

        PGDB = New NpgsqlConnection(PGConnection.ConnectionString)

       Try
            PGDB.Open()
            PGCommand = New NpgsqlCommand(TestSQL, PGDB)
            PGAdapter = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(PGCommand)
            PGAdapter.Fill(TestData)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            If Not PGAdapter Is Nothing Then
                PGAdapter.Dispose()
            End If

            If Not PGCommand Is Nothing Then
                PGCommand.Dispose()
            End If

            If PGDB.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
                PGDB.Close()
            End If

            If Not PGDB Is Nothing Then
                PGDB.Dispose()
            End If

            If Not TestData Is Nothing Then
                TestData.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

    Friend Function GetDirectoryEntry() As DirectoryEntry
        Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry()
        dirEntry.Path = "LDAP://<ADSERVERIP>/DC=<DOMAIN>"
        Return dirEntry
    End Function

    Friend Function GetActiveDirectoryUsername() As String
        Try
            Dim MyDirectory As DirectoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry()
            Dim search As New DirectorySearcher(MyDirectory)

            search.Filter = String.Format("(&(SAMAccountName={0}))", Environment.UserName)

            'Use the .FindOne() Method to stop as soon as a match is found
            Dim result As SearchResult = search.FindOne()

            If result Is Nothing Then
                Return ""
            Else
                Return result.Properties("samaccountname").Item(0).ToString
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Active Directory Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            Return ""
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

All of this code works perfectly if I leave the **LAN Manager authentication level** set on ***Send LM & NTLM responses***, but if I change it to ***Send NTLMv2 response only*** as is required by our new partner, it throws an exception on the `PGDB.Open()` statement.  From the debug log:

```
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlConnection.NpgsqlConnection(NpgsqlConnection())
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: HOST = <PGSQLSERVER>
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: PORT = <PORT>
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: PROTOCOL = 3
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: DATABASE = testing
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: USER ID = <PGSQLUSERNAME>
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: SSL = False
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: SSLMODE = Disable
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: TIMEOUT = 15
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: POOLING = True
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: CONNECTIONLIFETIME = 15
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: MINPOOLSIZE = 1
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: MAXPOOLSIZE = 20
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: SYNCNOTIFICATION = False
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: COMMANDTIMEOUT = 20
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: ENLIST = False
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: PRELOADREADER = False
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: USEEXTENDEDTYPES = False
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: INTEGRATED SECURITY = True
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ConnectionString Option: COMPATIBLE = 2.0.11.92
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlConnection.Open()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Get NpgsqlClosedState.Instance
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Get NpgsqlClosedState.Instance
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlClosedState.Open()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Attempt to connect to '<PGSQLSERVERIP>'.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Normal  Connected to: <PGSQLSERVER>:<PORT>.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlStartupPacket.NpgsqlStartupPacket()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlStartupPacket.WriteToStream()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlStartupPacket.WriteToStream_Ver_3()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.WriteString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String written: user.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.WriteString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String written: <PGSQLUSERNAME>.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.WriteString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String written: database.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.WriteString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String written: testing.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.WriteString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String written: DateStyle.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.WriteString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String written: ISO.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlState.ProcessBackendResponses()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   AuthenticationRequest message received from server.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlStartupState.Authenticate()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlPasswordPacket.NpgsqlPasswordPacket()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlPasswordPacket.WriteToStream()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.WriteBytes()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Unable to find resource string Log_BytesWritten for class PGUtil
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   AuthenticationRequest message received from server.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlStartupState.Authenticate()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlPasswordPacket.NpgsqlPasswordPacket()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlPasswordPacket.WriteToStream()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.WriteBytes()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Unable to find resource string Log_BytesWritten for class PGUtil
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.ReadString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Get NpgsqlEventLog.LogLevel
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String read: FATAL.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.ReadString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Get NpgsqlEventLog.LogLevel
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String read: XX000.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.ReadString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Get NpgsqlEventLog.LogLevel
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String read: could not accept SSPI security context.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.ReadString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Get NpgsqlEventLog.LogLevel
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String read: The token supplied to the function is invalid
 (80090308).
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.ReadString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Get NpgsqlEventLog.LogLevel
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String read: src\backend\libpq\auth.c.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.ReadString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Get NpgsqlEventLog.LogLevel
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String read: 1024.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Entering PGUtil.ReadString()
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   Get NpgsqlEventLog.LogLevel
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   String read: pg_SSPI_error.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Debug   ErrorResponse message from Server: could not accept SSPI security context.
2/22/16 12:32:58 PM 11452   Normal  An NpgsqlException occured: FATAL: XX000: could not accept SSPI security context.
2/22/16 12:33:02 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlConnection.Dispose()
2/22/16 12:33:03 PM 11452   Debug   Entering NpgsqlConnection.Close()
```

Oddly enough, if I try to connect using PGAdmin III using SSPI, there's no error.  I restarted the PostgreSQL service on the server (just in case), and still got the same error.  I even went as far as rebooting the whole server, but the error persists.

Now, if I change the Local Network Security policy setting back to ***Send LM & NTLM responses***, the application works normally, but we can't establish the RDP connection to our partner's system.  I even tried changing the policy setting to ***Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated***.  Again, my application will connect to the database without an error, but the RDP connection fails.

I guess the question boils down to this: Does anyone know how to get Npgsql to connect to a PostgreSQL database while the Local Network Security policy's **LAN Manager authentication level** setting is configured to ***Send NTLMv2 response only***?  Since everything else seems to work normally (as far as I can tell), this seems to be the point of failure.

**EDIT:** Since I'm working in Visual Studio 2015, I tried updating the version of Npgsql I was using through the NuGet console.  This updated the library to version 3.0.5.0, and I tested the connection again under the ***Send NTLMv2 response only*** setting.  This time the application's connection appears to have worked normally.  Just to be sure, I removed the 3.0.5.0 reference and added my older version back (apparently I'm on 2.0.11.92 - *yeah, yeah... I know*) and tested again, which gave me the same error as before.

It looks like whatever is causing the issue has been resolved with later updates to the Npgsql library.  Of course, that means that, unless there is a workaround for the version I'm using (2.0.11.92), I'm going to have to update ALL of my internal applications to make use of the newer library.  I *really* don't have time for all of that right now, so if anyone has a way to make this work, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@G_Hosa_Phat. 
I remember we had a big rework of the ntlm support, as you could check by testing recent 3.0.x versions and get it working...

There is no configuration options to change the behavior of ntlm authentication you could use.
I think you really would need to update your library.

But I would suggest you to update to the most recent 2.x version, instead of a 3.0.x as the changes of 3.0.x are beyond the ntlm support and it could break your existing systems.

Sorry to give you this bad news. :(

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  Unless our new partner can give me an alternate route to their systems, I guess it's time to start updating and testing my internal applications.  There's only about 50 of 'em...  Oh, well.

Comment: **@FranciscoJunior** I figured out that the 2.2.7 version (the latest 2.x release available on the NuGet site [https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql]) is probably going to be the way to go.  A number of my applications were built in VS2008 where the highest .NET framework available is 3.5.  When I try to add the 3.0.5 version to these, it can't find the necessary references.  That means I can either rebuild everything under the newer VS2015 to make use of the latest Npgsql version, or I can "drop back and punt" using the 2.2.7 version.  Guess which one I choose right now.  :-P